# Can Django save the data into TXT and possible edit it in Django Admin?

Tags: python, django

I've been using PHP .
Now I am using Django, and I have recently created a APP as my first Django/python project.

Who can understand and help me please?

```
class Record(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Title',max_length=100)
    #here......what should i do? Read_File_text
    filename = models.CharField('Filename',max_length=100)#while only save the file name and path,but django admin can edit text
                create_time = models.DateTimeField(u'Time',auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = verbose_name = 'Save to TXT'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        txt_hash = hashlib.new("md5", self.title.encode("utf8")).hexdigest()
        self.txt_path = 'txtfiles/%s.txt' % txt_hash
        txt_record = ContentFile(self.content)
        if default_storage.exists(self.txt_path):
            default_storage.delete(self.txt_path)
        default_storage.save(self.txt_path , txt_record)
        super(Record,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

*PHP CMS Admin function:*

```
function Read_File_text($filepath){
    $filepath=trim($filepath);
    $htmlfp=@fopen($filepath,"r");
    //Remote
    if(strstr($filepath,"://"))
    {
        while($data=@fread($htmlfp,500000))
        {
            $string.=$data;
        }
    }
    //Local
    else
    {
        $string=@fread($htmlfp,@filesize($filepath));
    }
    @fclose($htmlfp);
    return $string;
}
```

*PHP CMS ADMIN html:*

```
<textarea>
    echo Read_File_text('/static/txtfiles/qrw423asdfasdfasdfghjuo87.txt'
</textarea>
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you save the file contents in a text field in the database?

Comment: It's impossible to know what you are asking, or how that Python code is related to the PHP code (they don't seem to be doing the same thing at all.)